# How to post form data from Unit Test controller to custom controller | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, unit-tests, post-data

I have a custom module with form. I want to post values from unit test file to my custom module controller.

I tried 
$this->request = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['getPost'])
            ->getMockForAbstractClass();

```
    $this->request->expects($this->any())->method('getPost')->will($this->returnSelf());
```

It passed POST check but how to pass variable to controller.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you removed generated folder, cache:clear ?

Comment: Yes already done.